# Firebase Storage Android: How can I change the the filename of a downloaded file?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi am trying to download a file from the Firebase Storage in to the cache. That works fine. My Problem is that I can't change the entire filename. I can only change the prefix and the suffix. This is the filename that I am getting.

```
System.out: myImage -1452943744jpg
```

How can I remove the numbers and just change the filename to ***myImage***?

This is my code:

```
try {

        localFile = File.createTempFile( "myImage " ,"jpg");
        System.out.println(localFile.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    liftImage.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Local temp file has been created
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you request the system to create a temporary file, it generates a unique file name using the prefix and suffix you provide and a string that makes the name unique.  In this case the string is the number field you observe, probably derived from the current system time.  If you want complete control over the file name, you cannot use `createTempFile()`.

Instead, decide where you want the file to be located and create the file like this:

```
localFile = new File(XXXX, "myImage.jpg");
```

where XXXX is one of methods of `Context` that returns a directory:

- [getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir())
- [getExternalCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir())
- [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())
- [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

[This guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) describes some of the considerations for using cache, internal and external file storage.